# Woocommere orderby price loop issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get a simple shortcode to loop products based on price (descending). For some reason the below code doesn't order it by price, it just ignores the order attribute. Code is below:

```
function sort_by_price( $atts ){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'orderby' => 'price',
        'order' => 'desc'
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'sorter', 'sort_by_price' );
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Price isn't a recognized value for the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) `sortby` parameter.

Try the following args:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'meta_key' => '_price',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'desc'
        );
```

Comment: That works but its only showing 5 results rather than 20. If I raise the value to 50 I get 12, if i raise it to 100 I get 20. Very weird, there must be something elsewhere conflicting although my functions.php has no related code :(.

Comment: Sometimes meta queries are tricky because that automatically exclude items that don't have that meta key. However, in this case that shouldn't be a problem since most every product as a price.